# Intellij : Package name does not correspond to the file path

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Java/Maven project in intellij with the following file structure :

[image: My directory structure]

And the following line get me the error " Package name 'test.java.princ' does not correspond to the file path 'princ'"

[image: Line with the error]

In fact, it does this with *every* files in my project.

What I've tried :

- Rebuilding with maven
- Deleting project and importing it again
- Unmarking src/resources folder and marking them again
- supervision.iml has the correct folders as src and resources

Building works fine, with intellij or mvn command.

Comment: You are using `maven` - at least I can deduce it from having `target` directory. `main` and `java` directories are just a way Maven organizes project files and those directories are not part of packaging system. In your case you should just use `princ` as package name.

Comment: @MichałKrzywański You can put your comment as an answer for me to accept it, as it is more detailed than the current accepted answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not need the main.java just do package princ... for example: [Model.test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mZ77.png) for this project layout: [Project Structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xs8W.png) this gives me no errors.